# Is it possible to compile Hibernate with GraalVM?

Tags: java, hibernate, graalvm, byte-buddy, graalvm-native-image

My project contains a Hibernate dependency. Just want to compile it with GraalVM.
Actually, the compilation went well. But on runtime I have this.

```
2023-10-26 | 19:13:52.154 [        main] ←[34mINFO ←[0;39m | ←[36m                org.hibernate.Version←[0;39m | HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
Exception in thread "main" com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: No classes have been predefined during the image build to load from bytecodes at runtime.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:121)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.hub.PredefinedClassesSupport.throwNoBytecodeClasses(PredefinedClassesSupport.java:76)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.hub.PredefinedClassesSupport.loadClass(PredefinedClassesSupport.java:130)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:280)
        at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$DynamicClassLoader.invoker(JavaDispatcher.java:1383)
        at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:459)
        at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:452)
```

I tied almost everything, the last step, I updated the hibernate version to one of the [GraalVM-library-list](https://www.graalvm.org/native-image/libraries-and-frameworks/)
[image: screenshot of the compatible libs]

I played around with the native-agent to capture all required proxy-classes without success. Also heard about [Quarkus-Framework](https://quarkus.io/) which integrates and optimizes a lot for GraalVM but this is out-of-scope for me.

--> Has anyone ever managed to get Hibernate running in a native compilation with GraalVM?

Additionaly: I tried hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.10 instead (each time I collected the config files with the native-agent), this leads to

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:305)
```

**==> UPDATE!!!<==**

- I updated all to the current Hibernate, which was a hassle due to obsolete Criteria-usages, anyhow it worked.

[image]

Hibernate has a transitive dependency to byte-buddy, which kills me  currently related to the native compilation (@Rafael Winterhalter sorry :-) )

- I tried the experimental feature `experimental-class-define-support` to get all the necessary information for predefined classes, included it with the `-H:PredefinedClassesConfigurationFiles` definition.

BUT always still:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Defining new classes at runtime is not supported
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unimplemented(VMError.java:195)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:45)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at net.bytebuddy.utility.Invoker$Dispatcher.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$Dispatcher$ForNonStaticMethod.invoke(JavaDispatcher.java:1032)
        at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$ProxiedInvocationHandler.invoke(JavaDispatcher.java:1162)
        at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy63.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.injectRaw(ClassInjector.java:1638)
        ... 36 more
```

Has somebody a running sample with byte-buddy (in combination with hibernate) and graalvm compilation?

--> I added a little reproducer here: https://github.com/tonyre/HibernateSampleGraalVM

Comment: there is hibernate-graalvm [package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-graalvm) which is used by quarkus and [springboot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/5ff4a961b131a32c3b6417a4ebd0e55fe8d1a504/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L384) you can try.

Comment: Thank @ozkanpakdil you for your answer thats a good advice - I need to migrate to Hibernate 6 first, we are still using a very old one even with proprietary "Criteria" dependencies. ok, journey goes on...